# Good ways to capture website traffic statistics

Tags: language-agnostic

I tried AWStats but its painfully difficult to configure it(nginx logs dont rotate, stats dont get updated) and Google analytics has a lag of almost 12-14 hours. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is making an extra request like a small image 1x1 px beacon on a object, from like amazon s3 and enable logging for the bucket. an then use that log file to filter your stats. eg http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html